# Which one of the following represents the new variable that are created?

Tags: sas

The following is the code:

```
data work.test;
   set work.stuff(keep=jansales febsales marsales);
   array diff_sales{3} difsales1 - difsales3;
   array monthly{3} jansales febsales marsales;
run;
```

Which one of the following represents the new variables that are created?

```
A: jansales febsales marsales
B: monthly1 monthly2 monthly3
C: difsales1 difsales2 difsales3
D: diff_sales1 diff_sales2 diff_sales3
```

EDIT: The answer is C. But I think it should be A. Could anyone explain why?

Comment: Homework problem without sufficient work on the student's part.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for guidelines for On Topic questions.

Comment: @DomPazz, please see the EDIT.

Comment: I assume you meant `jansales` in the answer `A`.

Comment: @Tom, yes. You are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variables in answer `A` represent the variables read from the existing dataset `work.stuff`.  As such you would probably not consider them 'new'.

The variables in answer `C` are created by the definition of the array DIFF_SALES.  We know they are 'new' since they could not have come from `work.stuff`. They are not included in the explicit list of variables in the `KEEP=` dataset option.

However since there are no statements that assign any values to the variables in the DIFF_SALES array they will all be missing for every observation.